# Winding map doesn't make sense to me

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am looking at fundamental groups and about $S^1$, I was given the following

> Regard $S^1=\{z \in \mathbb{C};|z|=1\}$. For all $N \in \mathbb{Z}$ let $\omega_N:S^1 \to S^1; z \to z^N$  be the ma winding the circle around itself $N$ times in the anticlockwise directon with $\omega_N(1)=1$,

How does this wind around the circle $N$ times? $z$ is an arbitrary point on the unit circle $z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ for some angle $\theta$. Simply raising it to the power of some integer doesn't necessarily make it wind $N$ times.

Say if $\theta=\pi/4$. Then, $z^2$ would mean $z$ goes to $i$ i.e. $2 \theta=\pi/2$. This clearly hasn't winded around the original point $z$ twice. It just moved by an angle of $\pi/2$.

Someone explain this map to me please?

Comment: $S^1$ doesn't wind around points of the form $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ for any $\theta$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x:[0,1)\rightarrow S^1$ and $x(t)=exp(2i\pi t)$.

Then $\omega_N(x(t))=exp(2i\pi nt)$.

When $t$ goes from $0$ to $1$, $x(t)$ goes around the circle exactly one time while $\omega_N(x(t))$ does it $N$ times (and in anticlockwise direction), each point will be visited $N$ times. That is why $\omega_N$ is the map winding the circle around itself $N$ times.